# return the last non-zero value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame similar to this one.

```
name company count_2017 count_2018 count_2019 last_id
joe     abc     1           0         2         230283
cindy   bcd     0           2         0         239382
john    cde     0           1         0          238372
wang    def     0           0         3          1332
```

I need to return the last non-zero value and its year

```
name company count_2017 count_2018 count_2019 last_id.   year
joe     abc     1           0         2         230283   2019
cindy   bcd     0           2         0         239382   2018
john    cde     0           1         0          238372. 2018
wang    def     5           0         0          1332    2017
```

The 'year' column generated is the name of the last non-zero column. For example, in row 'joe', the last non-zero value is 2, then I return year 2019.

I used code

```
columns_first = df[[f'count_{yr}' for yr in range(2000, YEAR)]]
col_first = columns_first.columns
df["FIRST_YEAR"] = (columns_first.select_dtypes(float)
                 .gt(0)
                 .dot(col_first.str[-4:] + " ")
                 .str.split()
                 .str[0])
```

However, I couldn't return the last non-zero value, I can only get the first non-zero value. Is there anyway to fix this piece of code?

The return should be the original columns plus the year column as above
year
2019
2018
2018
2017

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: Notice two dataframe have different values for the last row

Comment: If you know how to get the first non-zero value, you can simply reverse the dataframe and use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `idxmax`

```
df.filter(like='count_').ne(0).iloc[:,::-1].idxmax(1).str.split('_').str[-1]
0    2019
1    2018
2    2018
3    2019
dtype: object
```

Comment: idx returns the maximum value, but in my case, the last non-zero value is not always maximum in the row.